# How to modify the fileManager url in Swift 4 to point to another directory

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

I have an app that I am developing in Xcode 9.2 and Swift 4 that creates a file and places it in the Exports folder of the Documents folder on the user's iOS device. The code I have currently looks for file in the Document folder of a user's iOS device.

```
let csvdocumentsPath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
```

I would like to change the code to point to the Exports sub folder of the Documents folder on the user's device so it can find the file.

I have searched the Apple documentation, the Internet, and Stack Overflow without finding anything that I could use to make the change. I am new to this and would appreciate any suggestions or recommendations you may have.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the Exports folder is created by the app I am developing and a file is placed in the Exports folder which is a sub folder of the Documents directory on the users device.

Comment: If you already have code that creates an Exports folder then why are you asking how to write code to access the Exports folder? You already have such code if you create the folder to begin with.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `URL`?

Comment: Please see my answer below. To create the folder is one thing, to access the contents requires that the url path be directed to that folder and file.  As I mentioned, I am new to this and needed to learn the syntax to append the path, which was not something I could find. Thanks ! :)

Comment: But in order to create the folder, you would have needed the same code you just posted in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I needed to append the path by adding the Exports folder as below:

```
let csvPath = csvdocumentsPath?.appendingPathComponent("Exports").appendingPathComponent(fileName3)
```